# Setting "connect to folder" property in Active Directory VB.net

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

I need to set the Home Directory property to:

Connect: H: To: (my folder path)

How can I do this in VB.Net?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried googling for an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link:

[How Can I Assign a New Home Drive to a User Who Doesn’t Have One?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/02/06/how-can-i-assign-a-new-home-drive-to-a-user-who-doesn-t-have-one.aspx)

And then combine it with one of the many examples on this page:

[Working with the Active Directory in VB.Net](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/30894-working-with-the-active-directory-in-vbnet/)